# Shell Variable in awk regexp

Tags: bash, awk

```
pods=$(kubectl get pods  | awk '/e2e-test/ && !/$HOSTNAME/')
```

I would like to filter and retrieve all pods in the kubectl result which start in "e2e-test", but which are different from the hostname. I tried different ways but they all seem ignore the variable.

Comment: Could you please post sample output of `kubectl get pods` and what is expected output too in your question, for more clarity.

Comment: Does ["How do I use shell variables in an awk script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes `'` don't expand variables, double quotes `"` do. This should work:

```sh
pods=$(kubectl get pods  | awk "/e2e-test/ && !/$HOSTNAME/")
```

On the other hand: You are using awk only to filter lines here, so this might be easier to read and maintain:

```sh
pods=$(kubectl get pods  | grep 'e2e-test' | grep -v "$HOSTNAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason bash fails expand `$HOSTNAME` variable is because it is quoted inside `'` quotes.

This is working as design.

The simplest dirty trick is to exclude the `$HOSTNAME` variable from the quote by replacing it with `'$HOSTNAME'` , like this:

```
pods=$(kubectl get pods  | awk '/e2e-test/ && !/'$HOSTNAME'/')
```